# How to wait for a given time and only perform last function call

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

Let's say I have a class named `Person`, with variables like `firstName` and `lastName`. I am listening to changes in these variables using a reactiveCocoa-framework, but let's say I'm only using the built in KVO-listening, like the `didSet{}`. So assume I have this code:

```
let firstName:String { didSet{ self.nameDidChange() }}
let lastName: String { didSet{ self.nameDidChange() }}

func nameDidChange(){ print("New name:", firstName, lastName}
```

Every time I'd change either the first name or the last name, it would automatically call the function `nameDidChange`.
What I'm wondering, is if there's any smart move here to prevent the `nameDidChange` function from being called twice in a row when I change both the `firstName` and the `lastName`.

Let's say the value in `firstName` is `"Anders"` and `lastName` is `"Andersson"`, then I run this code:

```
firstName = "Borat"
lastName = "Boratsson"
```

`nameDidChange` will be called twice here. It will first print out `"New name: Borat Andersson"`, then `"New name: Borat Boratsson"`.

In my simple mind, I'm thinking I can create a function called something like `nameIsChanging()`, call it whenever any of the `didSet` is called, and start a timer for like 0.1 second, and *then* call `nameDidChange()`, but both of these `didSet`s will also call `nameIsChanging`, so the timer will go twice, and fire both times. To solve this, I could keep a "global" `Timer`, and make it invalidate itself and restart the count or something like that, but the more I think of solutions, the uglier they get. Are there any "best practices" here?

Comment: You could add a Bool, `isChangingName` that is `false` by default and set that way in `nameDidChange` then `nameIsChanging` could use a `guard` to ensure it is `false`, set it to `true` and then start the delayed operation with a timer or `perform( , with: , afterDelay: )`

Comment: I think you should keep in mind that by adding an artificial delay, the user may interpret it as feeling "slow" or disconnected. Is there really a need to delay calling the function? If you do go the delay route, there should be *some* visual indication that the app is doing something.

Comment: @Zig I only need a delay of 0.01 second to prevent it, as they will be set at the same time. This is only for when they are set programmatically at the same time. Aside from this, I need them to call the function if they're changed separately as well. It's to prevent each of them to fire an url request when it's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I think you just need to delay the call to name changed until the user has "Stopped" typing.

Something like this:

```
var timer = Timer()

var firstName: String = "Clint" {
    didSet {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            self.nameDidChange()
        })
    }
}

var secondName: String = "Eastwood" {
    didSet {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            self.nameDidChange()
        })
    }
}

func nameDidChange() {
    print(firstName + secondName)
}
```

Everytime the first or second name is changed it will stop the timer and wait another 0.2 seconds until it commits the name change.

**Edit**

After reading the comment by Adam Venturella I realized that it is indeed a debouncing technique. It would be useful to google the concept if you would like to learn some more about it.

Here is a simple Playground that illustrates the concept:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var timer: Timer? = nil

func nameDidChange() {
    print("changed")
}

func debounce(seconds: TimeInterval, function: @escaping () -> Swift.Void ) {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: seconds, repeats: false, block: { _ in
        function()
    })
}

debounce(seconds: 0.2) { nameDidChange() }
debounce(seconds: 0.2) { nameDidChange() }
debounce(seconds: 0.2) { nameDidChange() }
debounce(seconds: 0.2) { nameDidChange() }
debounce(seconds: 0.2) { nameDidChange() }
debounce(seconds: 0.2) { nameDidChange() }
```

The output:

```
changed
```

The nameDidChange function was executed only once.

Comment: Putting a name to a face so to speak, this technique is called “debouncing”

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but instead of timers you can try to utilize `Date` to see when if they were fired right after each other or not. Also note that `.timeIntervalSince1970` returns the number of seconds since 1970 so I multiplied it by 100 to get a better precision.

```
var firstName:String! { didSet{ self.nameDidChange() }}
var lastName: String! { didSet{ self.nameDidChange() }}

var currentDate: UInt64 = UInt64((Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 100)) - 100

func nameDidChange(){
    let now = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 100)
    //You can add a higher tolerance here if you wish
    if (now == currentDate) {
        print("firing in succession")
    } else {
        print("there was a delay between the two calls")
    }
    currentDate = now
}
```

EDIT: Although this doesn't run on the last call but rather the first call but maybe this might help / spark some ideas

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to coalesce calls to `nameDidChange()` is to call it via `DispatchQueue.main.async`, unless such a call is already pending.

```
class MyObject {
    var firstName: String = "" { didSet { self.scheduleNameDidChange() } }
    var lastName: String = "" { didSet { self.scheduleNameDidChange() } }

    private func scheduleNameDidChange() {
        if nameDidChangeIsPending { return }
        nameDidChangeIsPending = true
        RunLoop.main.perform { self.nameDidChange() }
    }

    private func nameDidChange() {
        nameDidChangeIsPending = false
        print("New name:", firstName, lastName)
    }

    private var nameDidChangeIsPending = false
}
```

If a single UI event (e.g. a touch) result in multiple changes to `firstName` and `lastName`, `nameDidChange()` will only be called once.